# Any Cons of declaring varchar2 variables to maximum length in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

In PL/SQL, if we create a variable `name` with `varchar2(100)` and then assign a value with length of `50` to the variable, then the total memory used is `100` characters.

but if you declare it as `varchar2[4000]` or more it will use only the `50` characters.

Does a `varchar` column always allocate only what you have assigned?

Also, if this is the case, is it a good practice to declare all `varchar2` variables to *max length* as the memory would be dynamically allocated? Please clarify. Thank you

Comment: perhaps this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882073/impact-of-defining-varchar2-column-with-greater-length

Comment: Actually, thats the post which actually confused me.     
If the variable is declared with a size 1 to 3999 (11g+) / 1999 (10g or earlier), memory will be allocated for the maximum length (i.e. VARCHAR2(100) will require at least 100 bytes of memory).
If the variable is declared with a size 4000 (11g+) / 2000 (10g or earlier) or greater, memory will be allocated according to the size of the data stored. So, when the memory gets allocated dynamically when declared it maxlength, then why declare with smaller length

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong there. varchar2(100) uses one extra byte than the raw data, to store the length as an unsigned byte).

For max lengths over 255, an extra 2 bytes than the raw data are used, to store the length as an unsigned 16-bit (2 byte) integer.

So yes, there's a small penalty.

- use fixed width char(n) if your values are (mostly) the same length (no extra bytes)
- use varchar(n), with n < 256 if all your values will fit (1 extra byte)
- use varchar(4000) otherwise (2 extra bytes)

I wouldn't worry about the bytes -  just use whatever is convenient.

Comment: Would there be any impact on memory allocation if I create the variables as below: entity  varchar2(4000):=null;
                               entity_v varchar2(4000):=null;
                               r_id       varchar2(4000):=null;
                               i_cnt     varchar2(4000):=null;

Comment: @prat negligible

Answer (score 0):

I guess data integrity would be a concern if we use a blind size apart from memory. How can we be sure of the data size if we don't know what we are storing. And what if the value exceeds the 4000 mark ?

Besides I have experienced problems while creating index on combination columns with varchar2(4000). 
You would get something like this 
Error report: 
SQL Error: ORA-01450: maximum key length (6398) exceeded 
01450. 00000 - "maximum key length (%s) exceeded" 
*Cause: 
*Action:

Comment: ORA-01450 is actually related to your `db_block_size`

You either need to create a database with a larger `db_block_size`

or create a smaller index key.

Comment: @Gerry - I can go with second option as I have access to program but not to alter the db_block_size (No DBA access).

Comment: a smaller index key is probably better anyway.

Comment: Agreed on that any day. But the architecture is pretty old and situations demands one.